# How rare is Lapis Lazuli in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Minecraft gamer here. I recently started a new world of Minecraft, and I went down to y = 16 and started strip mining to try to find diamonds. However, I have almost two stacks of lapis lazuli now and zero diamonds. Is this normal, and how rare is Lapis Lazuli in Minecraft?

Comment: On which version are you? Because after 1.18 Y level was extended to -64, and now diamonds are found most commonly between -50 and -64. And Lapis Lazuli are no rare at all, they're pretty common in the deep.

Comment: Not only that Lapis Lazuli is common finding, [they hold 4 to 9 items per one ore.](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Lapis_Lazuli#Mining) It's so easy to get stack of those.

Comment: @pinckerman I am the latest version (1.19?) so I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: @Skye-AT Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very rare honestly, I've seen them on caves below -50. For your best chances, find one of those new large caves.

Comment: Thanks Xendex!!